# Creating a custom route to map at the root of the website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

My routeConfig.cs file currently has:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I have an action in my home controller that responds at:

```
/home/trackUser/123
```

How can I modify my route config so this same action gets called at:

```
/trackUser.aspx?userId=123
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot check it right now, but try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "TrackUserAspx",
                url: "/trackUser.aspx?userId={id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "trackUser", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```